# In eclipse , how to find path of jsp which is in different folder under webcontent

Tags: html, jsp

I am working on small application.
I use Eclipse.
I put my jsp,css,js file under "webcontent" folder as below:

```
webcontent/css/common.css

webcontent/js/common.js

webcontent/jsp/login.jsp

webcontent/header/header.jsp
```

Now when login.jsp take reference of common.css file by this html line

```
"link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/common.css" media="screen" "
```

then it works.

But when login.jsp take reference of header.jsp by

```
jsp:include page="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/header/header.jsp"
```

then it's not working.

So my question is how to get reference of header.jsp from login.jsp

Comment: The CSS file is downloaded by webbrowser via an URL. The `<jsp:include>` is executed by webserver via a file path during generating the HTML output before it get sent to the webbrowser. It's not downloaded by the webbrowser via an URL. That's the difference.

Answer (score 0):

`jsp:include page="/header/header.jsp"`